# Attaching a promise to another result

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I am working with two promises and have simplified this to make things easier to look at.

Note Cars and ServiceRecords are 2 different tables.

I would like my end dataset to look like this:

```
car = {
make: Honda,
color:red,
id:12,
serviceRecords:[
      {type: oil change,
       customerHappy: Yes,
       id:1
       carid:12
       },
      {type: oil change,
       customerHappy: no
       id:2
       carid:12
       }
     ]
}
```

First Promise

```
getCar() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
      // find the car we want
      const car = Xrm.WebApi.retrieveRecord('car', `${id}`);
      if (car ) {
        resolve(car ); // send the car
      } else {
        reject(Error('No Car Found!'));
      }
    });
  }
```

Second Promise

```
hydrateCar(car) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const services:any = Xrm.WebApi.retrieveMultipleRecords('servicerecord', `?$filter=carid eq ${car.id}`).then((results) => {
        for (let i = 0; i < results.entities.length; i++) {
          const result = results.entities[i];
           car.serviceRecords=result;
        }
        resolve(car);
      });
    });
  }
```

Call the function

```
this.getCar().then((car) => {
      console.log('car', car);
      return this.hydrateCar(car);
    })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
    this.loading = false;
  }
```

All I get back is the last iteration of the service record. I would like the key car.ServiceRecords to be an array of all the records.

Comment: What is the language/type of that first block? It looks like JS, but doesn't have quotes around strings.

Comment: @DarrylNoakes is JS  he forgot the quotes

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Comment: @Wyck No, why? The `console.log('car', car);` before the call has nothing to do with this. It's the `new Promise()` call inside `hydrateCar` (and probably also in `getCar`) that should be removed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
hydrateCar(car) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Xrm.WebApi.retrieveMultipleRecords('servicerecord', `?$filter=carid eq ${car.id}`).then((results) => {
      const serviceRecords = []; 
      
      for (let i = 0; i < results.entities.length; i++) {
        const result = results.entities[i];
        serviceRecords.push(result); 
      }
      
      car.serviceRecords = serviceRecords;
      resolve(car);
    });
  });
}
```

The issue you're facing is that you're overwriting the car.serviceRecords property in each iteration of your loop in the hydrateCar function. Instead, you should accumulate the service records into an array.

Comment: Yup your right! Been long day and I just saw that. Thank you!

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!